# Group and root persmission with FTP and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I have a vps. I have installed wordrpess. But everytime I install or try to make edits, I need to do it with ssh (root account) since the FTP account I created which has been added to the admin group does not have enough permissions to edit files.

I am wondering what should I be doing in order for the FTP account to have all the root privileges. And I dont have to use the root (ssh) account all the time. This ftp account is system account too. And every time I try to make a change, i get 550 CHMOD error.

And I am running Ubuntu on my vps with vsftpd.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never do this with a `root` account.  Make a dedicated account for this and assign the permissions you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to ftp as root but you should be able to do so according to

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=96366

> Edit the files /etc/vsftpd.ftpusers and /etc/vsftpd.user_list and remove the 'root' line from each file.

The file might be different depending on what distribution you are using.